# How to make google maps center and pan across a route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map on my web page. What I would like it to do is to be able to always center the map on a road or route I created on a road. So that when you pan left or right, it is always centered on the road and you are able to follow along the road by just clicking left or right. How am I able to implement this feature? Thanks a lot!